# Win Forms: How to Bind Property of UserControl In DataRepeater to Collection Item itself

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datarepeater

I am using a data repeater from Visual Basic Power Packs (`Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater`) in .Net 4.0 (c#) winforms project.
I am binding it (setting the `DataSource` property) to a generic `List<T>`. T is just one of my business classes.

The control I have placed in the data repeater is a UserControl.
The UserControl has a public property of type T called `MyItem`.

I want to bind the `MyItem` property of the UserControl to the actual item of type T in the collection, but it does not work. I can bind to one of the properties of type T, but not the collection item itself. *Note, I'm not trying to bind it to the whole collection, but rather the member of the collection that goes with that row in the data repeater (the current item).*

**What can I type into the `dataMember` parameter of the `DataBindings.Add` method to make this work?** I have tried `"."`, `"/"` and `""` with no avail.

Here's my collection object:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string SomeProperty {get; set;}

    public MyClass Self
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
        set
        { 

        }
    }

}
```

Here is my user control:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{


    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MyClass _myItem;
    public MyClass MyItem
    {
        get 
        {
            // this never gets called
            return _myItem;
        }
        set {
            // this never gets called
            _myItem = value;
            // Do something with _myItem
        }
    }

    private string _APropertyToBindToOneOfMyItemsProperties;
    public string APropertyToBindToOneOfMyItemsProperties
    {
        get
        {
            // this gets called
            return _APropertyToBindToOneOfMyItemsProperties;
        }
        set
        {
            // this gets called
            _APropertyToBindToOneOfMyItemsProperties = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code in the control that contains the data repeater,
which is responsible to load the data repeater with data:

```
    var MyCollection = new List<MyClass>();
    MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() {SomeProperty = "Value1"});
    MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() {SomeProperty = "Value2"});
    this.MyUserControl1.DataBindings.Add("APropertyToBindToOneOfMyItemsProperties", MyCollection, "SomeProperty"); // this works!
    this.MyUserControl1.DataBindings.Add("MyItem", MyCollection, "/"); // can't get this to work!
    this.MyUserControl1.DataBindings.Add("MyItem", MyCollection, "Self"); // can't get this to work either!

    this.MyDataRepeater.DataSource = MyCollection;
```

Comment: What is `lookupDocuments`, I thought `MyCollection` should also be the `DataSource` of your `MyDataRepeater`?

Comment: using `DataBindings`, the third parameter should always be a `Property`, if there is not any desired property, you have to define the property in your class (whose an instance is passed as the second parameter) first.

Comment: @King King, that has been changed to MyCollection. Sorry.

Comment: @KingKing, I could not get your work-around to work. I have edited my question to encompass that.